# Accessing Objects from ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I have an arraylist of objects that I am sending from class "Testing" to class "Subjects", but can't access some of the methods in the Subjects class.

I would like to be able to simply send an arraylist of "Subject" objects (from the Testing class) to a method in the Subject class and be able to use other methods within the Subject class.

```
public class Subject {
    private String subjectName;
    private String courseCode;

//getters and setters for subjectName and courseCode
```

I can access the following method if I just call it from the Subject class, but not from the Testing class.

```
public String getDiscipline(){
    int a = courseCode.length()-3;
    String discipline = courseCode.substring(0, a);        
    return discipline;
}
```

In the method below, I can return and print objects and call the method I want, but only for one object...

```
 public List<?> allDisciplines(ArrayList<?> inputSubjects){

    for (int i = 0; i<inputSubjects.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(inputSubjects.get(i)); //this returns all the 

//objects, but why won't this work instead?: inputSubjects.get(i).getDiscipline(); 

    }

    //initialise new arraylist
    List<String> dis = new ArrayList<>();

    dis.add(getDiscipline()); //This works, but only for whatever single 
                              //object I used to call the allDisciplines 
                              //method with 
                              //

    return dis;
}
```

In another class , I pass the object array "subjects" into the allDisciplines method of the Subject class.

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Testing program = new Testing();
    program.start();
    }

    public void start(){
    //gets the data from a file, converts it into "Subject" objects with 
    //subjectName and courseCode
```

The following works because it's only sending one object through and I only get one result.

```
    subjects.get(3).allDisciplines(subjects);
```

But if I try to access the allDisciplines method from the Testing class, I can't because it's not static and if I make the class static, it needs the private ints to be static which then don't change between iterations of my loops and I end up with the same value for fields.

```
allDisciplines(subjects); //does not work - can't see the allDisciplines 
                          //method
```

I am not sure whether the problem is because I can't access the method outside of its class or because I am not properly referencing the objects in the arraylist.

Thanks for any help you can give me - I am quite confused!

Comment: Where is `allDisciplines` defined?

Comment: change `ArrayList<?>` to `ArrayList<Subject>`

Comment: It's in the "Subject" class, the same as `getDiscipline`

Comment: @Oleg - thank you!!! that has done the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `allDisciplines` method. It should be static. You seem to not quite understand generics. I rewrote it for you:

```
public static List<String> allDisciplines(ArrayList<Subject> inputSubjects){


    //initialise new arraylist
    List<String> dis = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Subject subject : inputSubjects) {
        dis.add(subject.getDiscipline());
    }
    return dis;
}
```

I looped through the subjects passed in and added the discipline of each to a new array list and returned it. I also changed `List<?>` to `List<Subject>` because we are expecting the client code to pass a list of subjects.

Another shorter way to implement this:

```
public static List<String> allDisciplines(ArrayList<Subject> inputSubjects){
    return inputSubjects.stream().map(Subject::getDiscipline).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now you can call `allDisciplines` by

```
Subject.allDisplines(subjects)
```

in `Testing`.

Comment: That works perfectly - the main problem was the ArrayList<?> to ArrayList<Subject>. Thanks very much.